# Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): in C:\wamp\www\project\classes\Login.php on line 55

Tags: php, mysqli, wamp

Using WAMP. Trying to set up a development environment for an existing website.

Backed up and copied everything over from production server to a local computer, including exported MYSQL script with all the structures and data.

Website uses authentication. Tried to login, but after hitting on Login button get the following Warnings from PHP in this order:

> **Warning:** mysqli::mysqli(): in C:\wamp\www\p\classes\Login.php on line
> 55
>
> **Warning:** mysqli::set_charset(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
> C:\wamp\www\project\classes\Login.php on line 58
>
> **Warning:** Login::dologinWithPostData(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
> C:\wamp\www\project\classes\Login.php on line 59

All warnings are coming from Login.php class, which is inside classes folder. The source code for this file and entire login project is here:

> https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal/blob/master/classes/Login.php

Line **55** has no descriptive Warning message whatsoever. Line **55** in **Login.php** is this:

```
$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Those constants are set like so in a different, includes file called **db.php** located inside **config** folder:

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost"); 
define("DB_NAME", "projectdb"); 
define("DB_USER", "root"); 
define("DB_PASS", "");
```

mysqli and mysqlnd are both loaded as shown in the following image:

[image: php extensions]

Comment: you're using a seperate class for this? show more or full code.

Comment: Your server may not have the mysqli (or myqlnd) extension installed.

Comment: problem could be in your class then.

Comment: sorry Douglas, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I was able to replicate these errors by either having no mysql running or a missing database. Fixing the problems and your code runs fine. Perhaps your missing some of the error output?

Comment: Is the password correct? Is the server up? Did you check PHP error log?

Comment: Works now. All services were running. Rebooted MySQL service. Checked db.php again and it had wrong password. Set correct password. Must have been an I/O problem with Notepad++ when editing db.php